# Why doesn't chrome support BLE on Android tablet?

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to work out why the Bluetooth Web API isn't working on my tablet.  The tablet is an Android 4.4.4, Galaxy Tab E.  When I use [this demo page](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html?allDevices=true) in Google Chrome version 64, I get this error message:

```
Requesting Bluetooth Device...
with {"acceptAllDevices":true}
Argh! NotFoundError: Bluetooth Low Energy not available.
```

But when I try out a BLE app, [such as this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.alt236.btlescan),  it seems to work fine, scanning bluetooth devices.

I have tried searching for supported OS for the web Bluetooth API, and it works on chrome on my phone, but it would be helpful if it worked on tablets too.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found it.  Web Bluetooth is only supported on Android 6.0 Marshmallow or later.  See https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md